# Interpret str as hex character sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, checksum

I am working on developing a checksum function where 4 bytes are converted to a string of characters in hexadecimal (eg. '00ABCDEF') listed below:

```
packet = "004100ff"
checksum = 0
for el in packet:
    checksum ^= ord(el)
print (hex(checksum))
```

Currently, the only way to obtain the correct checksum (0xbe) is to manually rewrite the string as packet = '\x00\x41\x00\xff' which cannot be done automatically.

**How could I make python interpret the string as if each 2 characters were bytes in hexadecimal to perform the checksum?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly.  This should work.

```
packet = "004100ff"
checksum = 0
bytes_string = [packet[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(packet), 2)]
for byte_string in bytes_string:
    checksum ^= int(byte_string, 16)
print(hex(checksum))
```

Answer (score 1):

> How could I make python interpret the string as if each 2 characters were bytes in hexadecimal to perform the checksum?

Use `bytes.fromhex()` to interpret the `str` as a series of hex digits:

```
>>> packet = "004100ff"
>>> bytes.fromhex(packet)
b'\x00A\x00\xff'
```

Note also that *iterating* over `bytes` will give you `int`, so no need for `ord()` any more:

```
>>> for el in bytes.fromhex(packet): print(el)  # or list(bytes.fromhex(packet))
... 
0
65
0
255
```